# GraphQL Nexus Union with List member

Tags: typescript, graphql

I'm working on what presumably is a simple problem, but I'm not sure how to actually implement it. Using GraphQL nexus I'm trying to create a query that returns an array of "bookmarks" or some errors. I have the following set up so far:

```js
    const Bookmark = objectType({
      name: 'Bookmark',
      definition(t) {
        t.nonNull.id('id')
        t.nonNull.string('title')
        t.nonNull.string('url')
        t.typeName
      }
    })

    const BookmarkResult = unionType({
      name: 'BookmarkResult',
      definition(t) {
        t.members('Bookmark', 'NotAllowedError', 'NotFoundError', 'UnknownError')
      }
    })

    const BookmarkQuery = queryField('links', {
      type: 'BookmarkResult',
      resolve: async () => await pipe(getAllBookmarks(), foldW(of, of))()
    })
```

This functions and will return an array of bookmarks, or one of the error types. But they types are obviously mismatched, as I should be returning `[Bookmark]! | NotAllowedError | NotFoundError | UnknownError` which isn't allowed. So, I think I need to create another objectType with a field in in that resolves the array like this:

```js
    const BookmarkSuccess = objectType({
      name: 'BookmarkSuccess',
      definition(t) {
        t.nonNull.list.field('bookmarks', {
          type: 'Bookmark',
          resolve() {} // Where my issue is
        })
      }
    })
```

If my query is resolving the union, do I also have to resolve the `BookmarkSuccess` object in order to add it in?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. In case anyone else is stuck with this problem, I resolved it in with the following code.

```js
const Bookmark = objectType({}) // same as above
const BookmarkList = objectType({
  name: 'BookmarkList',
  definition(t) {
    t.field('bookmarks', {
      type: nonNull(list('Bookmark'))
    })
  }
})
const BookmarkResult = unionType({
  type: 'BookmarkResult',
  definition(t) {
    t.members('BookmarkList', 'NotAllowedError', 'NotFoundError', 'UnknownError')
  }
})
const BookmarkQuery = queryField({}) // same as above
```